# Sorting Entry Fields in Movable Type 5 CMS

Tags: content-management-system, movabletype

My CMS is currently Movable Type 5.04. The attached screenshot is how I check in Compose Screen of MT CMS.

[image: Compose Screen]

And it appears in the new entry create page with the following order.

```
- Location 5
- Job Description 5
- Bio 5
- Job Title 5
```

I would like to change the order into following.

```
- Job Title 5
- Location 5
- Job Description 5
- Bio 5
```

Is there any way to do so? I have checked in the `cfg_entry.tmpl` file and the above Entry fields were not there as there were custom fields. Could you please help me sort them like above?

Comment: Is upgrading an option? I believe in 5.1 drag and drop rearranging of fields on the entry editing page was added.

Comment: Upgrading is not an option. But we have authorized to change from code and database. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I have not done this before, but colleagues inform me it is practically not solvable on the releases where rearranging is not already possible.

Comment: I'm kind of lost when you say "Upgrading is not an option."  Movable Type Version 5.04 has known security vulnerabilities that make it inappropriate for use in production.

If you are already on MT 5.x, doesn't it make sense to upgrade to 5.14, which is considered a secure release, and take the issue off the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the order of the fields are stored into the permission table, in 'permission_entry_prefs' field. (and there is a matching field for the page)

the row with blog_id 0 is the user defaults, and each blog's raw will override the default for this blog.

and the format is very simple: comma delimited list. you should find there something like "title,text,tags,assets". just reorder them for your liking.

If the user will toggle on and off fields, I'm not sure if the original order will return or not. if it does, then a simple plugin can solve it in more permanent way.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing this by recreating the custom fields in the wanted order (MT pulls them from the DB in a specific order, sorted by ID IIRC). If you have existing data, then you need to delete the fields *definitions* (not the data) then recreate them in the order you want changing just their numerical ID (not anything else).

I'm traveling and busy at the moment so can't dig into details. But study how CF are defined in the DB and how to simply reorder them by ID.